# Import attribute values in the gimbal

Tags: java, android, gimbal

Please inquire about the gimbal.
In the gimbal place in the getValue continue to occur NullPointerException.
code below.

```
 placeEventListener = new PlaceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {
            String beaconName = visit.getPlace().getName();


            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "KeyAll : " + visit.getPlace().getAttributes().getValue("X").toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Err : " + e.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            };

            beaconRegiste(beaconName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisitEnd(Visit visit) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "End of " + visit.getPlace().getName(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you please debug your code and tell me the exact line in which you get exception?

Comment: sorry, visit.getPlace (). getAttributes (). getValue in ( "X"). toString () it does not find the value of the getValue ( "X"). But I tried to specify an attribute in a gimbal manager.

Answer (score 0):

Gimbal had the data internally. Therefore , Gimbal.resetApplicationInstanceIdentifier () the appropriate call were hayeoseo success .